# Scala/Play How to use JSON read to handle JSON value that can be string or array and always return Set[String]

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have the following class in my play server and the JSON Reads used for validation

```
case class Foo(name: String, link: String)

val fooReads = (
  (__ \ "name").read[String] ~
  (__ \ "link").read[String]
)(Foo.apply _)
```

I have changed the model to allow multiple links instead of one so i can expect array of strings in the input JSON:

```
case class Foo(name: String, link: Set[String])

val fooReads = (
  (__ \ "name").read[String] ~
  (__ \ "link").read[Set[String]] // it works this way
)(Foo.apply _)
```

I want to make it back compatible so it can handle JSON value of `"link"` with string along with array of strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the operator `orElse` on json `Reads` to create your custom reader:

```
val readsSet: Reads[Set[String]] = Reads.of[Set[String]].orElse(Reads.of[String].map(str => Set(str)))

val fooReads = (
  (__ \ "name").read[String] ~
  (__ \ "link").read[Set[String]](readsSet)
)(Foo.apply _)
```

Comment: Too quick @vdebergue ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Reads.orElse` combinator:

```
val fooReads: Reads[Foo] = (
  (__ \ "name").read[String] ~
  (__ \ "link").read(Reads.of[String].map(str => Set(str)).
    orElse(Reads.of[Set[String]]))
)(Foo.apply _)
```

Comment: Thank you too for the answer, both are the same and work!